# SQL php on different pages to Insert (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this piece of PHP code, it works when I placed it on my index page (**index.php**), but would do nothing if I put it in another page, i.e. **add.php**

*For example:*
Having that code into my **add.php** page, I tried to go to: **www.myhost.com/add.php** 
and nothing would happen.
But if I copy that code to **index.php** and go to the page **www.myhost.com/index.php**
It will add another row in my SQL table.

Why is that?

```
<?php
        $server="mysql.server.com";
        $user="randomUsr";
        $pass="randomPwd";
        $db="randomDB";

    $link=mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `Battery` WHERE `ID`");

    $query = "INSERT INTO  Battery (ID,Type,Owner,Charge,Time)
        VALUES ('1','Lily002','Maisnow','15','2015-04-22 17:20:28')";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);

    header("Location: index.php"); //this one is comment out when copied to index.php

?>
```

l

```
#   Name    Type       Collation    Attributes  Null    
1   ID      int(16)         No      None          
2   Type    varchar(8)  utf8_unicode_ci       No    None         
3   Owner   varchar(32) utf8_unicode_ci       No    None         
4   Charge  int(16)         No      None         
5   Time    datetime        No      None
```

**NOTE**: the SQL query runs fine on phpmyadmin

NSERT INTO  Battery (ID,Type,Owner,Charge,Time)
        VALUES ('1','Lily002','Maisnow','15','2015-04-22 17:20:28')

Comment: Is ID a primary key in your Battery table? You have a hard coded '1' in there, but primary keys must be unique. So it would work the first time and fail the rest of the time.

Comment: but if I add it into index.php I can add as many times as I wanted to. the ID is actually integer type...

Comment: If you add it into index.php you would create an infinite redirection loop because the last line redirects you index.php.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? If so, what have you tried, and what were the results?

Comment: @ChipDean Hey,on the index.php I comment out the last part of header(....)

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try to enter the query on phpmyadmin or a database access program like Dolphin?  Does it error out?

As Chip Dean suggested, it is likely a problem that you have ID hard coded.  The nomenclature suggests it is a primary key, which must be unique.

Are you getting results added to your database?

Comment: I'm getting results added to the SQL fine. For both `phpMyAdmin` using query `INSERT`, and `/index.php` using the PHP code above. It only not working when I copy it into the `add.php` and let `index.php` to display data only

Answer (score 1):

AS has already been pointed out here by Chip Dean and Marshall Tigerus, you may have a problem with your declaration of static values in your SQL query, so try this:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO  Battery (Type,Owner,Charge,Time)
        VALUES ('Lily002','Maisnow','15','2015-04-22 17:20:28')";
 mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
```

Does this work on all pages (even if the database has an empty ID value, at least showing this is the reason it wasn't working originally)?

If this doesn't work, please share what the `mysqli_error` outputs.

Comment: Hey, if I tried that, my SQL table will not be updated.
Noob question: how can I get the `mysqli_error` outputs? My hosting does not allow any third-party database access program for security reason. Therefore I cannot use Dolphin. (and I don't know how to use Dolphin to be honest.

Comment: The mysqli_error output will display on the browser window if the query failed, You should set an error catch as I have exampled for all your SQL queries where you're getting problems

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html it may also be a good idea to encase your `TIME` name in backticks for MySQL

Comment: No error ;-( and the` add.php` automatically switches to `index.php` even when I deleted the line `header(....)`